# Live() with custom events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, live

I am using a event normalizer for the mouse events and the touch events.  That way, I don't need to maintain 2 pieces of code : one that responds to the touch events and the other one to the touch events.

It works fine, but I cannot have it to work with the live() function.

At the end of the normalization process, the normalized event is triggered this way:

```
var touchMouseEvent = normalizeEvent(type, event, event.pageX, event.pageY);
$(event.target).trigger(touchMouseEvent);
```

I tried to have the live event to work using those calls:

```
$('.MyClass').live('TouchMouseEvent', function(){...});
$('.MyClass').live('normalizeEvent', function(){...});
$('.MyClass').live('touchMouseEvent', function(){...});
```

but NOTHING WORKS.

Typically, the trigger for custom events are called as a string like $('.Class').trigger('customName'), so I wonder if this is why I am struggling with that.

Here is the code I using for the normalization.
https://gist.github.com/2375726

Thanks!

Comment: Please use `.on()` as `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: Will do, but it was doing some test and I was using on() for those tests and it didn't work.

Comment: Custom events didn't work with `.live` in jQuery 1.3.x. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.7.2.  I think live() was introduced in 1.4 so I should be OK.

Comment: Is `MyElement` dynamically created by any chance?

Comment: `.live()` may be depreciated, but that's no reason for it to not work. If it isn't working with `.live`, switching to `.on` isn't going to automagically make it work.

Comment: yes, MyElement is dynamically created.  This is why I was using the live() function so I don't have to bind the events everytime I have a new object created.

Comment: sorry, my example does not make sense, it should have read $('.myClass').live(...). since it the object with the ID does not work is not there when the page is ready, it will never be bind... At least I think...

Comment: @Alexandre You are using `.live()`, the element doesn't have to exist when the page is ready. That's the purpose of using it!

Comment: More than likely you just aren't binding to the correct event type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if live() will work on custom methods/events its based off delegation. Delegation itself relies on actual DOM events being fired, but they're delegated down to the document.body level. Try using bind() instead.

Comment: I think you are right.  I used .delegate() and it work fine. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of using the live() function, I use the delegate function.

For example:

```
$('#wayPointList').delegate('.deleteWayPoint', TouchMouseEvent.UP, function(){
//do something here
});
```

Works like a charm!
Thanks everyone for your answer/suggestions.